# asp.net core 5 partial view will not render

Tags: asp.net-core

In a razor view I have

```
    <partial name="_BusinessBaseRatesPartial" />
    <partial name="_BusinessBaseRatesPartial.cshtml" />
    <partial name="~/Views/CountAnalysisReports2/_BusinessBaseRatesPartial.cshtml" />
```

3 different attempts to get a razor view that is in the same directory as the outer/main razor view to render. But it just ignores these lines and the rendered html just contains the above 3 lines.

I've used partial views before without problems and am following the Microsoft docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial?view=aspnetcore-5.0

This razor view (the outer one not the partial) has other if blocks and foreach stuff all working fine.

Comment: Have you made sure that the partial view is discoverable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorry i've figured it out, I was missing a file called   _ViewImports.cshtml in the Views folder, when I added that file, containing the line:

```
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
```

it worked OK